# Update Excel Table Range in Microsoft Graph REST API

Tags: excel, microsoft-graph-api

I want to update a table inside a spreadsheet using the Microsoft Graph REST API for Excel.  Reviewing the documentation, I can POST:

`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/root:/thisSpreadsheetName.xlsx:/workbook/worksheets/thisWorksheetName/tables(‘thisTableName')/Rows`

along with a body like:

```json
{
    "values": [["Jan-15-2016", "49", "37"]],
    "index": null
}
```

This command will indeed add the row.  However, it does not update it to be included in the table.  When I view the spreadsheet in Excel for Windows or Excel Online, the highlighted area for the table does not include the new rows.

We are working on creating a turn-key solution where a web site fills in a bunch of values (variable number) into a previously created spreadsheet, and then updates the range for a pivot table (which uses the table name), making it available to an end-user.  However, I don’t see anyway of making this turn-key if the user has to go in and update the table range themselves.

How do we make sure the new rows are included in the range of the table?

Comment: For anybody else who comes across this, and is suffering from the incredibly poorly documented Microsoft Graph REST API, the issue in this case was that there were cells below the table with content in them.  As a result, the API still put my values into the row below the table, but did not update the table bounds to include the new row.  Make sure all cells below your table are empty.  The API returns incorrect error codes and often "general internal errors", telling nothing and making it difficult to develop for.   Even the MSFT people here on StackOverflow don't know how this API works.